# Setting up enviroment variables in Windows 10 to use java and javac

Tags: java, path, environment-variables, javac, windows-10

I got a new laptop with Windows 10 and I want to set it up so I can use `java` and `javac` from the command line.

I have searched online but all the guides are for previous versions, and I don't want to mess around with something I don't understand.

Answer (score 95):

Just set the path variable to JDK bin in environment variables.

```
Variable Name : PATH 
Variable Value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin
```

But the best practice is to set JAVA_HOME and PATH as follow.

```
Variable Name : JAVA_HOME
Variable Value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

Variable Name : PATH 
Variable Value : %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: Do not forget to restart the terminal, i.e. the "cmd", (not the computer) through which you checked the "java -version" or wanting to run any other program using CLI

Comment: Since the Java folder doesn't exist on a new Windows10 installation, that is a misleading and worse than useless response.

Comment: @johnrubythecat a java 8 / windows 10 setup can be done with a jdk directory tree like what's used in this answer.

Answer (score 38):

Here are the typical steps to set JAVA_HOME on Windows 10.

1. Search for Advanced System Settings in your windows Search box. Click on Advanced System Settings.
2. Click on **Environment variables** button: Environment Variables popup will open.
3. Goto **system variables session**, and click on New button to create new variable (HOME_PATH), then New System Variables popup will open.
4. Give **Variable Name: JAVA_HOME**, and Variable value : Your Java SDK home path. Ex: **C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_151** Note: It should not include *\bin*. Then click on OK button.
5. Now you are able to see your JAVA_HOME in system variables list. (If you are not able to, try doing it again.)
6. **Select Path** (from system variables list) and **click on Edit button**, A new pop will opens (Edit Environment Variables). It was introduced in windows 10.
7. Click on New button and give **%JAVA_HOME%\bin** at highlighted field and click Ok button.

You can find complete tutorials on my blog :

> [How to set JAVA_HOME in 64 bit Windows 10 OS](http://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/java8/java-8-how-to-set-java_home-on-windows10.html)

Answer (score 12):

- Right click **Computer**
- Click the **properties**
- On the left pane    select **Advanced System Settings**
- Select **Environment Variables**
- Under the **System Variables**, Select **PATH** and click **edit**,
  and then click **new** and add path as **C:\Program

  Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin** (*depending on your installation path*)
  and finally click **ok**
- Next restart your command prompt and open it and try *javac*

Answer (score 8):

To find the env vars dialog in Windows 10:

```
Right Click Start
>>  Click Control Panel  (Or you may have System in the list)
>>  Click System
>>  Click Advanced system settings
>>  Go to the Advanced Tab
>>  Click the "Environment Variables..." button at the bottom of that dialog page.
```

Comment: Just to update my orignal answer. I have found RapidEE to be a much better way of editing/maintaining env vars in windows:
https://www.rapidee.com/en/about

Answer (score 1):

Its still the same concept, you'll need to setup path variable so that windows is aware of the java executable and u can run it from command prompt conveniently

Details from the java's own page: https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml
That article applies to: •Platform(s): Solaris SPARC, Solaris x86, Red Hat Linux, SUSE Linux, Windows 8, Windows 7, Vista, Windows XP, Windows 10

Comment: while it says at the top that it applies to win 10, there is no section for win 10.  Is it the same as win 8?

Comment: Try and see if you can find the similar things in windows 10 corresponding to windows 8 that u see in the link. The underlying concept hadn't change set path to tell windows where to look at to run your commands that u dont want to have to type out the full directory of that command

Answer (score 1):

if you have any version problems (javac -version=15.0.1, java -version=1.8.0) 
windows search : edit environment variables for your account
then **delete these** in your windows **Environment variable: system variable: Path** 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

**then if you're using java 15**
environment variable: system variable : Path
 **add path**   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin 
is enough

**if you're using java 8**

create JAVA_HOME

environment variable: system variable : JAVA_HOME
**JAVA_HOME** = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271

environment variable: system variable : Path
**add path** = %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: Before I wasn't aware about this! Always leave it as it's! After a good lesson right now I'm too much aware about this! What's a silly things made me mad! It's a awesome solution & save the day. Thank you [tharsikan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8963098/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding Environment Variable simplified with screenshot.
Check the below URL and you should be able to do without any trouble.

https://itsforlavanya.blogspot.com/2020/08/environment-variable-simple-7-steps-to.html