# Android studio failed to open

Tags: android, android-studio

My OS is win10

I reinstalled my system，and then set environment variables like：

```
CLASSPATH  .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;
JAVA_HOME  E:\JAVA\JDK\
PATH
```

and when I installed AS and click the icon,there was nothing appeared.
I found in the folder, there were `studio.exe` and `studio64.exe`, both of them did't work.

and I also tried to find `studio.bat`, but there were no file like this.

My question is how to get my AS working?
This is my first question and I eager to get it solved ,
Thanks!

Comment: did you add `JAVA_HOME` variable and set it's path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.~` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting up enviromental variables in windows 10 to use java and javac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241179/setting-up-enviromental-variables-in-windows-10-to-use-java-and-javac)

Comment: of course..i did as other questions said,

Comment: reset your android studio may be help you .....

Answer (score 0):

I was similar issue, uninstalling java and update to latest version will solve issue.

 If not download android studio bundle from [android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set JAVA_HOME to **../Java/JDK1.x/bin/** also don't forget to set path for **android sdk** too.

if you do it right : type **java -version** on your command prompt and you get the information regarding installed java version.