# Installation issue with Oracle SOA suite 12C

Tags: oracle, java-8, soa, jdeveloper

I am trying to install new Oracle soa suite 12c on my Windows 10 64-bit system. As per the instructions I have downloaded both the compressed files and extracted the same in my E:/ disk.

I have also downloaded and set the path of current JDK (which is required for Oracle soa suite 12c installation). Now, when I am trying to install it using command prompt (in administrative mode), I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: completely agree with you. Thanks for sharing the information @halfer

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you downloaded the JDK (Java Development Kit), not the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) ??

Because the `java` executable that Windows has found still appears to be a JRE java rather than a JDK java, as suggested by the error message.

On my machine I have both both a JDK and JRE installed:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131   
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
```

So you may have something similar.

If you DON'T have a jdk folder there, then maybe you only got the JRE.

If you DO have the jdk folder, what you need to do is make sure that the java under the JDK is the one that is used for the install.

To do that, you do it with the PATH environmental variable, and make sure the path to the JDK happens before the path to the JRE.

[setting up enviromental variables in windows 10 to use java and javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241179/setting-up-enviromental-variables-in-windows-10-to-use-java-and-javac)

Remember to include the `bin` in the path.

It's probably also worth setting the JAVA_HOME variable while you're setting environment variables - this should point to the root of your JDK install (that is, the same thing, but with out `bin` on the end).

You'll also need to make sure you open a new command shell.  Changes made to environment variables aren't immediately available within `cmd` windows that were already open.  So close that one and start a new one.

Comment: Thanks a lot GregHNZ!! Thanks for your time. You are right.When I explored more on  google, I got to know that I needed to actually shoot this command from my jdk\bin location:-                                                     
C:/Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin>java -jar E:\fmw_12.2.1.0.0_soa_quickstart.jar

Answer (score 0):

Software Requirements
Refer to the References section for a link to Oracle’s Certification Matrix.
The following software is required:

- Certified OS: Windows 7, 8, 10; Linux 64 bit OSX
- Oracle JDK 1.7 or 1.8 latest

So you have to download Oracle JDK 1.7 not any other to perform the installation.
also need to set the environment variables.

```
LAB_HOME   -->>    /home/<user> or c:\users\<user>
ORACLE_ROOT   -->>  <LAB_HOME>/Oracle
ORACLE_HOME   -->>  /<LAB_HOME>/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home
JAVA_HOME   -->>    Where JDK7 or 8 is installed. Varies by system.
```

Answer (score 0):

By default windows takes JRE path to run .jar files.

So try giving FULL jdk path while executing Jar.

Example: `C:/<JDK location>/java.exe -jar XXXXStart.jar`