# I have researched multiple ways to get my cmd line to recognize javac, but it still isn't

Tags: java

I have added the below to the environment variables path  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25. According to Google that's what was needed, but it still isn't working. I have attached a screenshot of exactly that

[image: screenshot]

I just want to try and run my java code from the cmd line. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What directory did you install Java into?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works on Windows, but I'm somehow missing `\bin`. Also, it would be interesting to see the output of `dir  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`.

Comment: You need JDK, and maybe `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241179/setting-up-enviromental-variables-in-windows-10-to-use-java-and-javac
Just check this out.

Comment: One: Prefer 64-bit Java on 64-bit Windows; Two: You need a JDK - not a JRE; Three: You need the "bin" folder; Four: You should install a more recent version (1.8 is up to [8u172](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)).

Comment: Also check the order of the `Path` entries. Your path to the *JDK/bin* should be above all other java related entries. Else you risk that Windows still uses the other entry for the `java` command.

Answer (score 1):

`javac` is not included in the JRE; you will need to download a JDK distribution.
After you have eg. the JDK 1.8.60, you can add
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin` to your `PATH` variable and `javac` will be available from the command line.