# Confused about CLASSPATH I think

Tags: java, classpath

I'm trying to build the open source application found at: https://github.com/linklayer/cantact-app

I've installed **Netbeans** and gotten to the point that I can create a new project. I got help doing this via **Netbeans** installed via APT opens but then closes, `"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"`

Now I'm still at a loss for how to set **CLASSPATH** in order to get the `"ant build"` command to work for cantact-app. When I look at `~/.netbeans/8.2/var/log/messages.log`, I don't see an actual **"CLASSPATH"**. Instead, I see a **"Boot & Ext. Classpath"**, a **"Application Classpath"**, and a **"Startup Classpath"**. Well I took the value of **"Application Classpath"** and did an `"export CLASSPATH=..."` for that long path. Now, `"ant build"` still gets a **"BUILD FAILED"** with message `"Cannot find NetBeans build harness. Check that nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir and nbplatform.default.harness.dir are defined..."`

Comment: Which OS are you working on?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it.  UBUNTU.  Using an osboxes originated Ubuntu 18.10 VirtualBox VM on Windows 10 host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting up enviromental variables in windows 10 to use java and javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241179/setting-up-enviromental-variables-in-windows-10-to-use-java-and-javac)

Comment: You can have a look here as well: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans]

Comment: Have you rebooted or logged out (of Ubuntu) since installing NetBeans?  If not, then it is possible that the package provided environment configuration files that have not yet taken effect for you.  You shouldn't actually need to reboot, nor even to log out, but logging out and then back in is probably the simplest way to ensure that your environment is properly configured for all installed packages.

Comment: Thanks John.  Darn.  Rebooting didn't help.  I'm trying other things...