# Java version command giving different results

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have set the environment variable for Java 7 but some software are picking Java 1.8 as default. When I am checking version through command prompt it is giving different results. How and why is this happening?

```
C:\Users\TanuGarg>java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

C:\Users\TanuGarg>javac -version
javac 1.7.0-internal
```

Comment: you also need to remove environment variable for java 1.8

Comment: write command `where java` or `where javac` which show you where your package installed may find useful information.

Comment: @Mustahsan I havnt set environment variable for java 8.

Comment: @Akash where java showing both the paths:            
C:\Users\TanuGarg>where java
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\IBM\Java70\bin\java.exe

C:\Users\TanuGarg>where javac
C:\Program Files\IBM\Java70\bin\javac.exe

Comment: i see two java installed one is in Oracle package and another is in IBM where only one javac found in IBM package, javac not found in Oracle. that's issue and idk how to fix it. but maybe reinstallation or set environment variable for oracle package will fix your problem.

Comment: set as oracle package path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241179/setting-up-enviromental-variables-in-windows-10-to-use-java-and-javac

Comment: One is the JRE, one is the JDK. Your JDK is a whole version behind.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you have two java versions (JRE) installed in your pc (one used by software and the other one is your jre in your JDK) and you have only one SDK version so your javac.

Solution:

> Set Path variable to your JDK bin folder and remove the path of the other jre from Path Variable.

Comment: I have set path variable for java 7 only.

Comment: check the path variable in system variables not the only the path variable in User Variables

Comment: try to set JAVA_HOME variable

Answer (score 0):

you can go to `control panel -> java -> java (tab) -> View.` This will list all the jre that are currently installed on your system(Where java will achieve the same thing). Here you can disable the jre-8 or any jre that might be latest install on your system by unchecking the `Enable` checkbox.

Also, if you want to run a software for a specific jre on a system that have multiple jre instanlled, you can directly go the jave jre path and run `java mysoftware` command from there

`e.g. C:\Program Files\IBM\Java70\bin > java mycommand`

Comment: I am using windows 10, here i am not able to find java option under control panel. Please suggest.

Comment: Type `java` in `run` and it should open up or you can do `Control Panel -> Program -> java`

Answer (score 0):

If you have several jdks in your environment like me
then, the only thing you can do is setting a proper path variable for your desirable jdk.

In my case, i have three jdks- 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8(javafx).

[image: My three jdk folders]

I have three jdk choices depending on the path variables.

For java 8 choice, i have to set the path variable look like image below.

[image]

where my javac.exe file is located under the folder name

C:\DEV\COMP\Java\javafx\jdk1.8.0_152

For java 7, i just set the path again pointing another one of jdk folders - jdk7.

[image]

It depends on which java version you should use by changing your java path if you just set the path variable properly.

Let's see the path variables so far.

[image]

The default jdk version is 1.7 because  first item on a path variable is pointed at the jdk 1.7 path.
I get a jdk 8 version, if I move the path of jdk 1.8 before that of jdk 1.7 again.

[image]