# Installation Android SDK tools / Java SE Development Kit not found

Tags: environment-variables, android-sdk-tools, java-home

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pzj3.jpg)

Setting a variable JAVA_HOME (+Path):
C:\Program Files\Java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin

Attempt to leave only for the user and only for system
Other solutions from:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241179/setting-up-enviromental-variables-in-windows-10-to-use-java-and-javac)
and many other sources offering similar solutions with changing the "JAVA_HOME" variable.