# error when firing command to build android build release in ionic android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build, ionic2

getting error when tried to build ionic android app for release update
**ionic cordova build android**

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /Users/manan/Library/Android/sdk
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
    
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241179/setting-up-enviroment-variables-in-windows-10-to-use-java-and-javac/32241360#32241360